# stat(char[], stat) returning -1 when string.c_str() = "c:/"

Tags: c++, file

Okay so I'm trying to make a file browser program, and I'm in the basics right now but this line here:

```
fprintf(stderr, "stat returned %i\n", stat(files[curser].c_str(), &st));
```

Says that stat is returning -1 (fail) and I am wondering why. Can anyone tell me? Here is the full source:

```
#include <SDL/sdl.h>
#include <SDL/sdl_image.h>

#include <SDL/SDL_audio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>

#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> // String stream library
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define TICK_INTERVAL    30

using namespace std;

extern "C" int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]);

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 16;

SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *message = NULL;

bool keys[322];

TTF_Font *font = NULL;
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 255, 255};
SDL_Color highlightColor = { 255, 0, 0};

Uint32 TimeLeft(void)
{
    static Uint32 next_time = 0;
    Uint32 now;

    now = SDL_GetTicks();
    if ( next_time <= now ) {
        next_time = now+TICK_INTERVAL;
        return(0);
    }
    return(next_time-now);
}


void init(){

    // initialize SDL video. If there was an error SDL shows it on the screen
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        SDL_Delay( 5000 );
       // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // make sure SDL cleans up before exit
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);

    // create a new window
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_DOUBLEBUF|SDL_HWSURFACE );
    if ( !screen )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Delay( 5000 );
     //   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Dir Reader", "Dir Reader");


    TTF_Init();
    //SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
   // joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);

}

void cleanup(){

     // we have to quit SDL
     SDL_Quit();
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void apply_surface ( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination ){

     // make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
     SDL_Rect offset;

     // give the offsets to the rectangle
     offset.x = x;
     offset.y = y;

     // blit the surface
     SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );
}

void apply_surface ( int sourceX, int sourceY, int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination ){

     // make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
     SDL_Rect offset;
     SDL_Rect sourceRect;

     // give the offsets to the rectangle
     offset.x = x;
     offset.y = y;
     sourceRect.x = sourceX;
     sourceRect.y = sourceY;
     sourceRect.h = source->h;
     sourceRect.w = source->w;

     // blit the surface
     SDL_BlitSurface( source, &sourceRect, destination, &offset );
}

void apply_surface ( int sourceX, int sourceY, int sourceW, int sourceH, int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination ){

     // make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
     SDL_Rect offset;
     SDL_Rect sourceRect;

     // give the offsets to the rectangle
     offset.x = x;
     offset.y = y;
     sourceRect.x = sourceX;
     sourceRect.y = sourceY;
     sourceRect.h = sourceH;
     sourceRect.w = sourceW;

     // blit the surface
     SDL_BlitSurface( source, &sourceRect, destination, &offset );
}

int getdir (string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dp;

    struct dirent *dirp;
    if((dp  = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL) {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return 1337;
}

int SDL_main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    printf("init.\n");
    init();

    font = TTF_OpenFont( "GOODTIME.ttf", 15 );

    bool done = false;

    string dir = "C:/";
   // dir = dir.substr(0, dir.size() - 1);

    int curser = 0;

    while(!done){

    vector<string> files = vector<string>();

    if(getdir(dir,files) == errno){
         printf("error number: %i.\n", errno);
    }

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                    done = true ;

            else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                keys[event.key.keysym.sym] = true;
            }

            else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP )
            {
                keys[event.key.keysym.sym] = false;
            }
        }

        if (keys[SDLK_x]){
            struct stat st;

            fprintf(stderr, "stat returned %i\n", stat(files[curser].c_str(), &st));

            if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)){

                if(files[curser][0] == '.' && files[curser][1] == '.'){
                    dir = dir.substr(0, dir.size() - 1);
                    dir = dir.substr(0, dir.find_last_of('/'));
                }

                else{
                    string temp = string(files[curser]);

                    dir += "/";
                    dir += temp;
                }
            }

            curser = 1;

            keys[SDLK_x] = false;
        }

        if (keys[SDLK_UP]){
           curser--;

            if(curser <= 0){
                curser = (int) (files.size() - 1);
            }

            keys[SDLK_UP] = false;
        }


        if (keys[SDLK_DOWN]){
            curser++;

            if(curser >= (int) files.size()){
                curser = 1;
            }

            keys[SDLK_DOWN] = false;
        }

        SDL_Rect rect;
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.y = 0;
        rect.h = 480;
        rect.w = 640;

        SDL_FillRect(screen, &rect, 0x000000);

        message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, dir.c_str(), textColor );

        apply_surface(0, 0, message, screen);

        for(int i = 0; i < (int) files.size(); i++){

            if(curser == i){
                message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, files[i].c_str(), highlightColor );
            }

            else{
                message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, files[i].c_str(), textColor );
            }

            apply_surface(0,  25 + (i * 15), message, screen);
        }

        SDL_Delay(TimeLeft());
        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }

    cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: posting 2 pages of source code for one line, isn't helpful in finding the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, actually *you* can tell yourself. If `stat` fails, it will set the `errno` variable to indicate why. You just need to find out what that's set to. You may also want to ensure that `files[curser].c_str()` itself is valid even though you've stated it's set to `"c:\"`.

Even if it *is* what you state, it may be that `stat` doesn't like working on the root directory in that form. This will depend a great deal on the implementation you're using (you should add that as a tag).

In other words, change your line to something like:

```
int x = stat(files[curser].c_str(), &st);
fprintf(stderr, "stat returned %d '%s' %d\n", x, files[curser].c_str(), errno);
```

---

For what it's worth (and that may not be much), the following program works fine under VS2008:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct stat st;
    int x = stat("c:\\", &st);
    fprintf(stderr, "stat returned %d %d\n", x, errno);
    return 0;
}
```

outputting:

```
stat returned 0 0
```

Comment: It just says "stat returned -1 0"...

Comment: @paxdiablo, or better yet use `perror` for a human-readable description.

Comment: That program isn't portable, as it might evaluate errno before the call to stat.

Comment: Way to miss the point, @Yuliy :-) That's why I used the phrase _"something like"_. Yes, snippets that I post here frequently _won't_ be bullet-proof. I don't want to give snippets which have a hundred lines of error checking code if the point I'm trying to get across can be shown in three lines, because (1) it's not necessary and (2) even _fewer_ people will read my answers :-)

Comment: paxdiablo: my point is that it's probably why William got -1 as the return from stat, but 0 for errno (which means "no error") in his comment above

Comment: Okay, I see now (apology offered) - fixed to cover that case.